# DELPHI Where can I add common library path in 10.3 Community version

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have just installed 10.3 Rio Community version and are trying to add mORMot-libraries to it.

But I can't find where I shall add it.

In my XE6-version it's in the Tools-menu but in 10.3 I can't find it.

Comment: Tools->Options->Language->Delphi Options->Library

Comment: I corrected the tag, and all the version information i the post. There is no such thing as XE10.

Comment: Ok, I searched for that tag but didn't find it.

Comment: @David: Fully agreed. I don't know why people keep on using that XE thing for the 10.x versions. And "XE10" (well, not "XE10.3") could stand for 4 different versions anyway, of which especially the latest is quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

search path is in Project->Options->Delphi Compiler->Search Path

attention: this options are available only after project creation

Answer (score 9):

The [mORMot documentation states](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_113):

> Download and uncompress the framework archives, including all sub-folders, into a local directory of your computer (for instance, `D:\Dev\Lib`).
>
> Then add the following paths to your Delphi IDE (in
>   Tools/Environment/Library menu):
>
> Library path:
>   `(...existing path...);D:\Dev\Lib;D:\Dev\Lib\SQLite3;D:\Dev\Lib\SynDBDataset`
>
> Search path:
>   `(...existing path...);D:\Dev\Lib;D:\Dev\Lib\SQLite3;D:\Dev\Lib\SynDBDataset`

[I have corrected the documentation](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_113) to add the `Tools->Options->Language->Delphi Options->Library` path suggested by Dave.

Comment: Ok, thank's. I missed that 'Tools->Language..' I never thought it could be there.

Comment: I rewrote this part of the documentation - there was a lot missing, including latest FPC information. I hope it helps.

Comment: O yes, it helped. :-) No problems after that I found the right Place in the menue - Tools->Options->Language->Library. Strange thow, that that they have put it in the Language tab.

Comment: Should I use this approach to try to resolve this error also ? :    [dcc32 Fatal Error] Project1.dpk(32): E2202 Required package 'rtl' not found

Answer (score 1):

versao delphi 10.3 Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Library